# Samsung galaxy s2 (i9100) part of touchscreen unresponsive

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, touchscreen

Just about week ago my phone started to randomly ghostclick in certain parts of touchscreen, so i started to debug issue and came to conclusion that part of touchscreen has became unresponsive and also phone sometimes click on those unresponsive areas by himself.

Here is affected areas:

[image]
[image]

As you can see the two vertical areas are unresponsive.
Top part of screen is okay (that's why i did not include).

Anyone has encountered such problem?
I have tried, full wipes and different ROM's nothing fixed problem.

Should i consult some sort of mobile technician?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is almost certainly a hardware problem and the touchscreen may need to be replaced.